# Do I use a case approach in this direct proof of divisibility?

Tags: proof-verification, proof-writing

I'm doing a simple direct proof exercise 4.20 from Hammack's Book of Proof.

`If a is an integer and a^2|a, then a is a member of {-1, 0, 1}`

I'm not sure if my approach is 1. correct   2. what Hammack had in mind

```
Case 1: a is not a member of {-1, 0, 1}

a = xa^2 where x is an int # definition of divisibility
1 = xa   #algebra
1/x = a  #algebra

a is not an integer, thus the P (a is an integer and a^2|a) is false, 
thus the proof isn't violated.

Case 2:  a is a member of {-1,0,1}
a=xa^2 
(a,x) = (-1,-1), (0,0), and (1,1)


So neither of the two cases disproves the proof.
```

Comment: What does "the proof isn't violated" mean ? What proof? What does "disproves the proof" mean. What proof?

Answer (score 1):

If this is to hold then $ma^2=a$ for some $m\in\mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $ma^2-a=a(ma-1)=0$. Necessarily, $a=0$ or $ma=1$. Suppose $a\ne 0$. Then $m\ne 0$, and so $a=1/m\in\mathbb{Z}$. The only values of $m$ for which $1/m$ is integral are $m=\pm1$. By extension, $a=\pm 1$.